# AWS EC2 dockerized Nodejs app to listen over ssl (443)

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a nodejs api dockerized running on an EC2 instance. The app itself is running inside the container on port 5000 and is mapped via docker-compose to 5000:5000.

I actually wanted the API to listen on the port I can access via https so I tried mapping the ports in the docker-compose like this "443:5000". I set an inbound rule in the EC2 security group for SSL allow access from anywhere but when I hit the IP or DNS name into my browser it is not responding.

```js
# Image source
FROM node:14-alpine

# Docker working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copying file into APP directory of docker
COPY ./package.json /app/

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git
# Then install the NPM module
RUN yarn install

# Copy current directory to APP folder
COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Is there anything I was missing?

```
version: "3"
services:
  nftapi:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '443:5000'
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      - postgres
      
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/data/postgres
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
  pgadmin:
    links:
    - postgres:postgres
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - /data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to curl on localhost inside your ec2 and check if it is working? How is your DNS reaching the ec2? Are you using a load balancer or a public ec2 instance?

Comment: I am not using any loadbalancer, I just have the docker-compose spin up the containers above and then created the inbound rule to allow 443 from anywhere. Then to my understanding I should get the API when I go on https://mypublicdnsec2

Comment: Have you got port 443 open on the EC2 instance (think firewall rules and such)? Have you tried the curl command as Nathan Ruiz has suggested? Also ... in the security config, did you choose https traffic?

Comment: i have an inbound rule on the instances security group for https (443) from anywhere. I dont know how to curl anything.

Comment: just go inside your ec2 and type curl 'https://localhost:443'

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused

Comment: is your docker image working with https? simply forwarding a simple http port to 443 won't make it https

Comment: I put the Dockerfile content of the API in the initial post. I dont know what is missing there. Are there https specific options for a docker image?

Comment: try adding HTTPS=true to your .env file

Comment: you would have to create the ssl certificates though, HTTPS is not as simple as HTTP. I recommend you to read this: https://blog.bitsrc.io/using-https-for-local-development-for-react-angular-and-node-fdfaf69693cd

Comment: Or, the way I would do is to keep the application running on http and run it behind a load balancer that's is accessed through https (think ALB on AWS or NGINX as a container)